If $d \mid a_*/(a,b)_*$ then $(d,b)=1$
Let $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $a_*$ denote the core (or radical) of $a$, i.e. $a_*=p_1 \cdots p_r$ if $a=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ and $1_*=1$. Suppose $d \mid a_* / (a,b)_*$, where $b$ and $d$ are positive integers. Prove that $(d,b)=1$.
I've tried to use the fact that $(a/(a,b),b/(a,b))=1$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and the fact that if $c \mid b$ and $(b,d)=1$ then $(c,d)=1$, but it seems that it is not of much use because the equations get reversed. Thanks in advance.
Edit: From the previous observation it would be enough to show that $(a_*/(a,b)_*,b)=1$ which kind of makes sense, since $(a,b)_*$ is removing all the prime factors of $b$ that $a_*$ may have.

Just do it for each prime. Show that if $ p \mid b$, then $ p \not \mid a_* / ( a, b)*$, which should hopefully be obvious after a while. $\quad$ Hint: $ p \mid (a, b)*$.

@CalvinLin Thank you, I began assuming $(b,a_/(a,b)_)>1=m$ so there is a prime $p \mid m$, then used your idea and got $p$ does not divide $a_/(a,b)_$, but $p \mid a_/(a,b)_$ by definition of $m$ and transitivity, a contradiction.

Can you write that up as a solution (to answer your own question) instead of a comment? Thanks!
